# Fine-grained realtime with Meteor.js (Socket.io ?)

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, socket.io, ddp

We are currently building a realtime multiplayer game, based on Meteor.js and Phaser.io.

Our problem is the following : Publication / Subscription system from Meteor is not fast enough, as we expected.

Up to 60 times per second, the client can call a method to update a published document. And it regularly happens that the player moves are freezed because of the limitation of writting each change in MongoDB, then checking changes with the observers and pushing to other clients. And if both players are moving at the same time (which can imply writting on the same document), the freezes happens more often.

Obviously, if I ask that, I'm already sure that the freezes come from the publication update time, and not from Phaser.io

So here is my question : how do I implement a "true" realtime system inside Meteor ?

I was looking for DDP, but the docs are really poor and do not let me think I can efficiently build the communication process with it. It seems there is absolutely no way to handle custom events between clients and server with DDP.

Of course, there is Socket.io, but it seems that many people are having troubles impleting it with Meteor.

What would you do ?
Which tools or way are the bests to solve the problem ?

Thanks you.

Comment: I'd not use Meteor.... I'd use something like Phonenix perhaps.  http://www.phoenixframework.org/

Comment: Have you tried Meteor Streams ? http://arunoda.github.io/meteor-streams/

Comment: Unfortunately, Meteor streams are not available anymore after Meteor 0.9.

I do not know Phoenix. I'll have look at it.

Currently, the main problem is that, though client can easily reach the server thanks to Methods, and even try to guess the result, there is no way to send a call from the server to the client.

Comment: Phoenix is built with Elixir. We do not know that language, and are using Phaser.io -> we need Node.js / Js.